# python calling function twice one after another but second storing value from first

Tags: python

I am using python so can someone tell me how to call same function twice in python but when you call it the second time it should be changed an already have value stored in it when you called the function the first time, so I basically mean you are calling the function first time and right after that you are calling it again but with the return value from the first time you called that function.

Comment: Please edit your post to include an example to demonstrate how this function will be used

Comment: `function(function(argument))`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a function that has both a parameter and a return value:

```
def myFunction(input):
    # do something with input
    return input
```

To have a second instance of the function use the result of the first instance, you can simply nest the functions:

```
result = myFunction(myFunction(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you can create function that will apply n-times

def multf(f, n, x):
        if n == 0:
            return x
        return multf(f, n-1, f(x))

so here we apply lambda sqr 3 times, it becomes f(f(f(x)))

sqr = lambda x: x**2

print(multf(sqr,3,2))

256
```